# angular-material change checkbox color

Tags: angular-material

I'm using checkbox of angular-material2. Currently the default color of checkbox is coming as purple color.
Looks like they have changed default color of checkbox from "primary" to accent.
Is there a way to get "primary"(green) color instead of purple without overriding css.
I tried giving color="primary" to  but that didn't worked.

Code : `<md-checkbox></md-checkbox>`

Import statement:

```
import {MdCheckbox} from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sFC0kfdzj7fxtUC3GXdr?p=preview

Comment: Change the "color" (https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) property should be the accepted answer. Someone looking for it is being buried on excption cases when they just want to change the color of a simple checkbox...

Comment: Someone who is using angular material most probably knows the answer you provided. But even more probably someone is looking for it because he wanted to use a color other than the 3 that work with your solution.

Answer (score 46):

Based on feedback from comments, updated my answer by removing '::ng-deep', but please read comment by @colin-fox, and understand how this will behave in global styling and at component level, many thanks!

For Angular Material 7, works for outline color and inside filled in color

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    opacity: 0.03 !important;
    background-color: #005691!important;
  }

.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #005691;
  }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, I would remove the opacity because it leaves a faded mark. Also, this doesn't change the color of the initial ripple.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me but for angular 9 we must removed '::ng-deep' to work it properly.

Comment: ng-deep will be depracated, I believe... I had work around, I posted it here somewhere.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This also works in Angular Material 11.x Great tip and a funny bit is that your sample also included the exact color setup i wanted !

Comment: Is ::ng-deep required? I removed it and it works fine.

Comment: @Halil it definitely shouldn't be required but the Angular team has made it difficult if not impossible to style things without ng-deep or without making the style global by putting it in styles.css (ng-deep not needed there). I mean we could just use selectors and put everything in styles.css for all Material related things but that seems a bit ridiculous

Answer (score 38):

You don't have to add css if you'r using theme, just add attribute color to `<mat-checkbox>`

`<mat-checkbox color="primary">Primary</mat-checkbox>`

> The color of a `<mat-checkbox>` can be changed by using the color property. By default, checkboxes use the theme's accent color. This can be changed to 'primary' or 'warn'
> [Checkbox | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#theming)

Comment: so if I want to use our corporate colors, outside of the theme, how do I change the color?

Answer (score 16):

One of the [standard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors) ways to do this is to utilize the /deep/ selector

```
mat-checkbox {
    color: rgb(0,178,0);
    /deep/ .mat-checkbox-background {
        background-color: rgb(0,178,0);
    }

    /deep/ &.mat-checkbox-focused{
        .mat-ink-ripple{
            background-color: rgba(0, 178, 0, .26);
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow you to override styles in components where Shadow Dom is enabled.

Answer (score 13):

This solution works well for me

```css
.mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: $your-color !important;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Default color depends upon the theme which you **@import**.

But angular material also provide way to customize the theme or for customizing the components like changing the color of **checkbox**.

**Steps of doing this as follow :-**

1.)  Import the _theming.scss file

```
 @import "../node_modules/@angular/material/theming";
```

2.) Specify the **accent** color i.e. color of check box you want to apply like below :-

```
  // customising of the mat-checkbox accordiing Theme. i am using pink indigo theme 
     bydefault so here I am changing the checkbox color from pink to grey.


    $candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);

    // here I am specify the grey instead of Pink.

    $candy-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-grey, 600, 500, 900);
    $candy-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

    // Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
    $candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

    // here I am only calling checkbox mixin because i only want to change the checkbox color     
    @include mat-checkbox-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't as helpful as the person doesn't want to and shouldn't change their entire theme just for a single components coloring

Answer (score 8):

Update for **Angular Material 15**:

```
.mat-mdc-checkbox.mat-mdc-checkbox-checked .mdc-checkbox__background, .mdc-checkbox__ripple {
    background-color: green !important;
    border-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: How do u do that, for intermediate state?

Comment: @Dominik, How can I change the tickmark color?

Answer (score 6):

Angular 7+

This will work for checkbox as well as the initial ripple color. If you just change the background for the checkbox, the initial ripple color won't update. This resolves the issue.

SCSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent {
    .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
        background-color: $your-color !important;
    }

    .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
        background-color: $your-color;
     }
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox.mat-accent {
    .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
        background-color: $your-color !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A combination of answers worked for me in angular 9

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  opacity: 0.03 !important;
  background-color: #005691 !important;
}

.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #005691 !important;
}
.mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #005691 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods(that i know ) to change the background color of mat-checkbox (angular 9)-

method 1 - by using color property of the mat-checkbox .

```
       <mat-checkbox
          id="{{ subtask.name }}"
          [color]="accent"
        >
          Check
        </mat-checkbox>
```

Limitation - You can only use color according to the angular material theme by this method .

method 2 - If you want to give custom colors to the mat-checkbox first track down the classes till the target class you want to change color of. [tracking of nested classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkFDh.png)

after that write like this in your style.css(global) file-

1st checkbox

```
.l0
  .mat-checkbox-checked
  .mat-checkbox-layout
  .mat-checkbox-inner-container
  .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #ffbf00 !important;
}
```

2nd checkbox

```
.l1
  .mat-checkbox-checked
  .mat-checkbox-layout
  .mat-checkbox-inner-container
  .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #4caf50 !important;
}
```

Result - [different color for different mat-checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t1U8.png)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with **Angular 10**:
In your **styles.scss**:

//Change background color

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #1f45cc;
}
```

//Change the border color for both checked and unchecked cases

```
.mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: #1f45cc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With beta.2 of Angular Material, the `color` attribute should work.

There were some issues with it before beta.2

> See the [commit](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/7ac29f8afa3b8b47a138bfffa3c59059b4f8f7c6) that fixed that issue.

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of the default checkbox color

```
md-checkbox .md-icon {
    background: green;
}
md-checkbox.md-default-theme.md-checked .md-icon {
    background: green;
}
```

read more here at [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/checkbox)

Comment: This is for angular-material 1.8. My question is for material2. Changing css is one of the way but I'm looking for a way to do it without changing/overriding css because angular-material2 itself has lot many themes. I want a way to use existing theme without overriding css.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think the latest version for `Angular-Material is 1.0.8`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Released version is 1.0.8. But angular-material2 is in alpha version and is yet to released. angular-material2 is for angular2.

Answer (score 2):

The following will keep frame grey when unchecked but change to custom color when checked:

***relevant-scss-file.scss***

```
mat-checkbox {
  &.mat-checkbox-disabled.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
   background: rgb(0,178,0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since deep is deprecated. In my view the right way to do it is using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.

ex:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then you just need to change the class

```
.mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: green;
}
```

You just need to be careful to deal with global css stuff. In SASS nested classes should handle it properly.

You can have more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672579/783364

Answer (score 2):

For me what has worked is the following:

```
<mat-checkbox class="tn-checkbox">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

In the css (or in my case sass):

```
.#{$wf__ns}checkbox {
  .mat-checkbox-ripple {
    .mat-ripple-element {
      background: $cool-blue !important;
    }
  }

  &.mat-checkbox-checked {
    .mat-checkbox-background {
      background: $cool-blue;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-ripple {
      .mat-ripple-element {
        background: $cool-blue !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:

The checked background color is changed to mat-checkbox-background within mat-checkbox-checked. **IF you want to modify the background color when it is not checked** just copy that part and copy it outside of mat-checkbox-checked.

**As for the ripple classes**, it turns out that the material has an animation when you press the button. That class controls the color of the animation, if you don't change it it will remain the same (pink).

If you do not change it by pressing the checkbox you will see a strange pink effect.

The other answers do not work for me although I rely on the first to develop it.

It may be from my version of angular that I leave below:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.25
Node: 13.3.0
Angular: 8.2.14
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of the border this way.(angular)

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox {
    .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
        background-color: #07abe9 !important;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-frame {
        border-color: #07abe9 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works.  On our JHIPSTER project, we have a `global.scss`.  Here is what you need to do if you do have a global.

1. Wrap your component html with a class.  Forexample:

```html
<div class="supplier-details-container">
  <!-- rest of your html here -->
</div>
```

2. In the `global.scss` or `global.css` write your css/scss like so (`Im using red to test`):

```css
.supplier-details-container .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Basically using css hierarchy wrapping the native angular material css with your component class that you use to wrap your component html.

Let me know if it works or not.  We can debug.

Answer (score 1):

For **Angular Material 15**
To go alongside @Dominik Brázdil answer -
You can use the mdc css variables to change the colour, you can find the different states in the inspect elements.

```
.mat-mdc-checkbox {
    --mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size: 16px;

    &.mat-accent {
        --mdc-checkbox-selected-focus-icon-color: #2E2E38 !important;
        --mdc-checkbox-selected-hover-icon-color: #2E2E38 !important;
        --mdc-checkbox-selected-icon-color: #2E2E38 !important;
        --mdc-checkbox-selected-pressed-icon-color: #2E2E38 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: &.mat-accent showing warning  "CSS nesting syntax is not supported in the configured target environment ("chrome119.0", "edge119.0", "firefox102.0", "ios16.0", "safari16.0") [invalid-@nest]"

Answer (score 0):

this solution works well for me

```html
/deep/.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #3490d3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
      background-color: $your-color!important;
}

.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background{
      background-color: $your-color!important;
}
```