# How to style template inside the component

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular2viewencapsulation

So, I want to pass a template to the component and render this template inside with style applied from this component, not from the calling component. Is it any way to do this without setting `ViewEncapsulation.None`?

I made a small stackblitz for that. I want `param button` also rendered green.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrpufe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend using `::ng-deep` at all. It is deprecated and in time will be removed for good.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984597/5048820).

I changed your code and added a container `div` for your HelloComponent. With a class on that div you can control the styles inside your component. Any style that you write like that in your main *style.css* file won't need `::ng-deep` or `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```css
// styles.scss 

  .hello-container button {
      background: green;
   }
```

```html
// hello.component.ts -> template

<div class="hello-container">
 ...
</div>
```

OR

even simpler:

You do not need the container `div`, just add this in your *style.css*

```
hello button {
      background: green;
    }
```

'hello' is the selector for your component and it will apply that style to EVERY button in your component.

Comment: thanks for the notice, yes it has been deprecated for a long time and also CSS WG has not agreed on an alternative yet it could take years and there are too many objections about that deprecation, Using global custom style sheets also may not be the best call.

Comment: Agreed. Both solutions work, but in the end, I personally prefer not to use ng-deep. Cheers :)

Comment: yeah, I was thiking about global styles, but maybe there's solution without them. a bit of context, this problem comes from the library project, so I would have to deliver global styles to the host app as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one

```
  styles: [`
   ::ng-deep button {
       background: green;
    }
  `]
```

> Use the ::ng-deep shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a
>   style down through the child component tree into all the child
>   component views. The ::ng-deep combinator works to any depth of nested
>   components, and it applies to both the view children and content
>   children of the component.

**EDIT:**
This deep selector has been deprecated for a long time and CSS Work Group has not agreed on an alternative yet. Untill there is a replacement I favor to use deep, because, while alternative solutions like wrapping the element with a div and styling globally is good to go, it has problems too, the biggest issue with it, it doesnt work inter-modules in angular. It is up to you to decide.

Comment: it's deprecated.