# Angular Material Change Theme Color of <mat-list-option> checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

Is it possible to change the color of the  checkbox using the material theme? For example, with a normal  you can simply do `<mat-checkbox color="primary">`. However something like `<mat-list-option color="primary">` does not seem to have any effect.

I couldn't find anything about this in the Angular Material API reference but surely there's a way besides changing the color manually (i.e. not using the theme) like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167149/angular-material-change-color-of-clicked-mat-list-option)?

Comment: `MatListOption` doesn't use the `color` option. So the only way to change color is 'manually'.

Comment: This component is really not mature, not only it doesn't play nice with angular theming system, but also it does not offer any state indicator (like .mat-checkbox-checked or .mat-radio-checked) at the option level. This make it really hard to style, if you can use mat-radio or mat-checkbox instead pass your way.

Answer (score 3):

Check this StackBlitz: [Custom option list](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-piu8mg?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Add this to your `style.css file`:

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox::after {
    color: red;
}

.mat-pseudo-checkbox {
    background: lightblue;
}
```