# Can I change the color of Angular Material checkbox with some custom color and how?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to do this, but is looks like it is only possible to change it to primary or warn.

Comment: Do you need CSS for it or dynamic code?

Comment: I think CSS would be enough. I'm new in Angular.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The proper way to control colors of Angular Material elements is to use differrent pallettes, but the functionality is limited. If you want more control, you can add custom CSS, and in most cases you will need to use `::ng-deep` to force your styles to apply, for example:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: violet;
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2u8ebm?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.css), where I changed the color of the border and background when it checked. You can follow this way to implement any styling you want.

If you're not familiar with `::ng-deep` and don't really understand, when you need it, you can look through [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787165/6053654) short answer.

### UPDATE 1

There is another one way via encapsulation disabling (thanks to @Ventura). It has a right to exist, but be careful if you decided to disable encapsulation, don't confuse with stylesheets, because it behaves differently from what you expect from default Angular logic regarding CSS.

For more info: https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components

SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981478/6053654

### UPDATE 2

The method is deprecated, see more info [**HERE**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) or [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep/46787165#46787165).

Comment: Thank you two. This is what I have done:                                                            ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, 
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, 
.mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, 
.mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate, 
.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, 
.mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    background-color:green !important;
  }

Comment: deep is deprecated.

Comment: @Ventura Is there any analog for now?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide here is the solution that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981478/783364 not sure if it's the best one but if you are careful with global css stuff it should be just fine.

Comment: @ararb78, that's right, but what if we need to customize AM styles? Do we have such an option in other ways? View encapsulation disabling is not ideal btw

Comment: since ng-deep is depracated, this solution worked for us with a JHIPSTER app, we have a global css and here is the complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339735/angular-material-change-checkbox-color/63852220#63852220

Comment: @Gel, yes, putting your styles into a global stylesheet will work in most cases, why not. But does it work with libraries like Angular Material? I'm not sure about that, but if so, I think it's a matter of taste, to keep specific rules in a global stylesheet, or store it into a specific component's stylesheet file to keep your style rules cleaner and better organised (IMO)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it works.  We are using Angular material.  Try it out.  Matter of taste or not, Im answering here, cause the method we used works for libraries such as angular material.  Atleast checkout the link, and the solution.  Answer here suggests using ng-deep, that will depracate soon as you have stated above.  So consider the approach in the link I provided.  Test it, then and only then can you say if its a matter of taste.  Understood, people do things differently, but thats not the case here, I am trying to solve the OPs question.

Answer (score 11):

You may use this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate, .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    background-color: red !important; /* Red background for example */
}
```

Comment: If you are using a newer version of Angular: Use /deep/ instead for ::ng-deep

Comment: deep is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code to change its box and its check icon:

```
/*  In case of using Angular 9+, Replace /deep/ with ::ng-deep */

/deep/ .mat-checkbox.mat-accent {
  .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border: 1px solid dodger-blue;
  }

  &.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid dodger-blue;
  }

  .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: dodger-blue !important;
  }
}
```

Angular Material Version: "7.0.0"

Comment: It works, just Replace '/deep/' with '::ng-deep' for Angular 9+ versions.

Answer (score 2):

These answers didn't work for me for indeterminate boxes. Following did:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background,
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #222d32 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your css.

```
::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
    background: red;
}
```

You should use ::ng-deep otherwise it will not work.

On your Html, use like this,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="values" [formControl]="val" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v">{{v.text}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #005691;
  }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was specifically interested in changing the color of the frame around the checkbox and the label text.   This worked for me:

```
div.mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: red;
}

span.mat-checkbox-label {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this, slight variation of other answers:

```
::ng-deep .mat-pseudo-checkbox.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
  background: $my-colour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: $your-color-code !important;
}
```