# Change border-color and background-color of mat-checkbox dynamically according to color value in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using `<mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>` and I want to changes its' color according to different color code values. How can I achieve this in angular 7. I know it can be done with css as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795199/can-i-change-the-color-of-angular-material-checkbox-with-some-custom-color-and-h?noredirect=1&lq=1). I want to change it dynamically like using `[ngStyle]` or some other way.

Comment: You cannot do this directly other than using the 'color' property to use primary accent or warn colors. You would have to override style. There are several examples of how to override checkbox colors here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the color of Angular Material checkbox with some custom color and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795199/can-i-change-the-color-of-angular-material-checkbox-with-some-custom-color-and-h)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this with ng-deep. For example, try the below code:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame {border-color: orange;}
```